# Why does Nightcrawler get called "elf"?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

Why does Nightcrawler get called "elf" by the X-Men?  I thought he was a mutant human like the rest.

Comment: Turns out he loves sitting on a shelf around Christmastime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual nickname (given by Wolverine) was "Fuzzy Elf". The reason was (from "Appearance" in http://marvel.wikia.com/Kurt_Wagner_%28Earth-616%29) :

- His body is almost entirely covered with a fine indigo-colored fur.

  *Source*:

  > It was Chris Claremont's scripting that evolved him into the swashbuckling hero he is today. Claremont stated that he took the idea that Nightcrawler thought "it was incredibly cool to be **blue and furry**."
- Nightcrawler has pointed ears

  [image]

Here's a card where the "Fuzzy Elf" nickname is stated (if http://marvel.com/universe/Nightcrawler is not enough of a source):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's because he has pointy ears.  Elves have pointy ears, hence the nickname.  But it's strictly a nickname; he is a mutant human, not an actual elf.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this is (and you may have to think about it a little) that Rogue and Wolverine call him Elf or Furry Little Elf because he looks like a blue furry little elf. That is the simplest and most straight forward answer I have ever given in my 43 yrs. But this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Does this answer say anything that other existing answers do not?

Comment: Since you're new to the site, think about what you could add to a question that already has an accepted answer. Perhaps you could improve your answer by showing illustrations of a 'classic elf' (whatever that may be in our collective opinion) and Nightcrawler side by side, pointing out the similarities.